# Test if a power series gives an automorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, power-series

If we have a function of several variables given by a vector $x$, is there a test to determine if the function written as a power series is an automorphism? (That is a one-to-one function with a unique inverse?)

e.g.

$$\overrightarrow{f}(\overrightarrow{x}) = a + \sum_na_n x_n + \sum_{nm}a_{nm} x_n x_m + \sum_{nmo}a_{nmo} x_n x_m x_o + ..$$

What conditions on the coefficients $a$ make this a one-to-one function?

For a simpler question what conditions are there for a function of a single variable? Some examples of one-to-one functions are: 
$f(x) = 3+x$, $f(x)=x^3 + 5x$,$f(x)=x^3+3x^2+8x+1$

So if we are just given the list of coefficients, is there a test to determine if it is one-to-one (without testing every value!). I can think of simple tests where the list of coefficients is finite but they don't seem to generalise.

Alternatively is there a way to parameterise the coefficients so that they give every automorphic function but no others? Or a different kind of series that only gives automorphic functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=(f^1,\ldots, f^n)$ be a vector-valued function of $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, whereby each $f^i$ is given by a power series, convergent when $|x|<\rho$ for some $\rho>0$:
$$f^i(x)=a^i+\sum_{j=1}^n b^i_j x_j+\sum_{j,\>k}c^i_{jk}x_jx_k+\sum_{j,\>k,\>l}d^i_{jkl}x_jx_kx_l+\ldots\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)\ .$$
Then $f$ is differentiable in the ball $|x|<\rho$, and its Jacobian at $0$ is given by the matrix $B=\bigl[b^i_j\bigr]$ encoding the linear terms of $f$ at $0$. If this matrix is regular, i.e., if ${\rm det}(B)\ne0$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ such that $f$ maps $U$ diffeomorphically, in particular: bijectively, onto some neighborhood of the point $a$.

This is a very general, but not a "quantitative" theorem. In any concrete case one has to do a lot of work to exhibit the size of such an $U$.